# Variable in function undefined / Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't get my function to work properly.

This ist my code:

```
function createPlayer() {
  var nation = new Array("Germany", "USA", "France", "Spain", "Belgium", "Nigeria", "Camerun", "Egypt", "Morocco", "SouthAfrica");

  var deFN = new Array("Andreas", "Daniel", "Kevin", "Lukas", "Timo", "Lennard");
  var usFN = new Array("Tyler", "Ron");
  var frFN = new Array("Lucas", "Mathis");  

  var deLN = new Array("Müller", "Meyer", "Ries", "Kellermann", "Werner", "König");
  var usLN = new Array("Stinson", "Wellington", "Booker", "James", "Owen", "Nolan");
  var frLN = new Array("Lefevre", "Bonnet");    

  var nationPlayer = nation[Math.floor(Math.random() * nation.length)];
  var namePlayer = new Array("");

  if (nationPlayer == Germany) {
    var namePlayer = deFN[Math.floor(Math.random() * deFN.length)] + deLN[Math.floor(Math.random() * deLN.length)];
  } else if (nationPlayer == USA) {
    var namePlayer = usFN[Math.floor(Math.random() * usFN.length)] + usLN[Math.floor(Math.random() * usLN.length)];

  } else if (nationPlayer == France) {
    var namePlayer = frFN[Math.floor(Math.random() * frFN.length)] + frLN[Math.floor(Math.random() * frLN.length)];

  } else {
    var namePlayer = "Other nation"
  }

  console.log(namePlayer);
}
```

First this function should pick one random nation of the nation array.
Then if the random picker picked one of these 3 nations, it should connect the nation, the first name and the last name to the variable Array "namePlayer"

(Sorry I'm a Newbie)

Comment: Learn to use your developer console. It will tell you the error in it. `(nationPlayer == Germany)` <-- That is not correct, same i=with al the rest of the conditions. It is looking for a variable named Germany, it is not the string Germany.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, can you be more specific? what variable is undefined? can you cut down the code at all? its enough that people might skip it, try to get only the amount needed to show the problem (could be valid right now).

Comment: http://jshint.com/, paste your code in there.

Comment: Try to remove the `var` in each `var namePlayer` in every `if`s

Comment: @epascarello Thanks! It works now! An thanks for the useful page!

Comment: @JordanHendrix I will try my best, thanks

Comment: @am05mhz It works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace `nationPlayer == Germany` to `nationPlayer == "Germany"`, because variable Germany is not defined.

```js
function createPlayer() {

  var nation = new Array("Germany","USA","France","Spain","Belgium","Nigeria","Camerun","Egypt","Morocco","SouthAfrica");

  var deFN = new Array("Andreas","Daniel","Kevin","Lukas","Timo","Lennard");
  var usFN = new Array("Tyler", "Ron");
  var frFN = new Array("Lucas" , "Mathis");

  var deLN = new Array("Müller","Meyer","Ries","Kellermann","Werner","König");
  var usLN = new Array("Stinson","Wellington","Booker","James","Owen","Nolan");
  var frLN = new Array("Lefevre", "Bonnet");

  var nationPlayer = nation[Math.floor(Math.random() * nation.length)];
  var namePlayer;

  if (nationPlayer == "Germany") {
    namePlayer = deFN[Math.floor(Math.random() * deFN.length)] + deLN[Math.floor(Math.random() * deLN.length)];
  } else if (nationPlayer == "USA") {
    namePlayer = usFN[Math.floor(Math.random() * usFN.length)] + usLN[Math.floor(Math.random() * usLN.length)];
  } else if (nationPlayer == "France") {
    namePlayer = frFN[Math.floor(Math.random() * frFN.length)] + frLN[Math.floor(Math.random() * frLN.length)];
  } else {
    namePlayer = "Other nation"
  }
  console.log(namePlayer);
}

createPlayer()
```

Comment: Tell them what they did wrong.... People do not learn by just saying "here"

Comment: Thank you so much!